# label alignment in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to do an extended (multiline) node description in a column layout by using the node label. I'd like the text to be right below a rectangular node. Something like:

```
  [ Node ]
  lines of my
  centred
  label
```

so I've tried:

```
.css({'text-valign':'bottom',
      'text-halign':'centre', 
      'text-max-width':nodeWidth})
```

which places the text in the right spot, however it also centre-aligns the text itself.

```
  [ Node ]
lines of my
  centred
   label
```

Any other 'text-halign' lays out the text as I want, but *also* value places the text in a corner. Is it possible to change this to get the label text aligned horizontally with the node, but have it left-aligned within the lines like a normal text paragraph? the standard CSS 'text-align' property doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've managed to work around this issue by adding an additional node below, with label aligned as text-halign:left, and text-valign:bottom (which would place the text on the bottom right corner) and then making the node body transparent and of size 0x0 so that just the label is visible. Not the most elegant solution, but it seems to do what I want.

Comment: could you explain more how you do that, to a new Cytoscape user (I'm using it through Dash/Plotly).  Is this a Group Node you are creating ?

Answer (score 0):

Only the documented style properties are available.  If you're looking for functionality not currently available, please file a Github issue: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new

For now, if the alignment to the left is really important to your app, you can align the text to the centre right of a node.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @maxfranz - that indeed improved the alignment but it also centres the text vertically around the node, so that if my label spans multiple lines, these will grow both _upwards_ and _downwards_ next to the node they're aligned to. I'd want the text to only grow downwards since it otherwise overlaps with other nodes in my layout, hence I was trying to use bottom alignment instead. I could have tried working around this by figuring out the line count for the label, and ensuring the node body is equally tall (thus lowering the anchor point) but this didn't seem very workable.

Comment: If you're using a newer version, most layouts should avoid overlap automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For any future viewers looking how to align their Cytoscape node's text content to center and you're using Cytoscape through Dash/Plotly.  This works as of late:

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape-two-nodes',
        layout={'name': 'preset'},
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '400px'},
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'one', 'label': 'Node 1', 'classes': 'node'}, 'position': {'x': 75, 'y': 75}},
            {'data': {'id': 'two', 'label': 'Node 2', 'classes': 'node'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}},
            {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two'}}
        ],
        stylesheet=[
        # Group selectors
        {
            'selector': 'node',
            'style': {
                'text-valign':'center',
                'text-halign':'center', 
                'content': 'data(label)'
            }
        }] 
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```